# Internet of Things Platform Starter: Failed to create container

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-iot

Created an Internet of Things Platform Starter service. As it did not start automatically, I started it manually:

```
STG/0 Failed to create container Apr 29, 2017 9:11:24 PM
API/1 Failed to stage application: staging failed Apr 29, 2017 9:11:24 PM
LGR/nullproxy: error connecting to 169.46.101.209:8081: dial tcp 169.46.101.209:8081: i/o timeout Apr 29, 2017 9:26:12 PM
```

Not sure, why a container is required.

Comment: It's all Diego now - containers you can ssh into.

Answer (score 1):

Node-red is running now. Looks like a glitch.